# How to remap controller buttons in newer RPG Maker games?

Tags: controllers, windows-10, windows

On RPG Maker games made on the older versions, when I pressed F1, it would bring up a remapping window. Now on games made using the newer one where it's like a contained browser (Electron?), nothing happens when I press F1.

The game doesn't detect Xinput controllers but it works with DirectInput ones. I can switch my controller between dinput and xinput mode. However, some face buttons are poorly mapped by default and I want to change it.

I think it goes without saying that I am not the developer of the games. When I tried looking up possible solutions to this problem, all I kept seeing are options on how a developer could set this up but not from an end user's point of view.

I know I can use remapping software like JoyToKey and just map the controller to corresponding keyboard keys while using it on xinput mode so it doesn't get detected by the game. But that's my last resort. I want to see if I can find any built-in solutions to this first.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @nondebug Windows

Comment: Do you know which engine this is specifically? RPG Maker MZ?

Comment: @qazmlpok not really. It can only be MV or MZ since those are the ones based on Electron.

Comment: RPG Maker apparently doesn't use Gamepad API, otherwise XInput should just work on Windows. I found a "Gamepad Extender MVZ" plugin that fixes this, but that's not helpful since you aren't the creator of the game. I think your best option is to use an app that can create a virtual DirectInput device from your XInput controller. It seems that an app called XInputPlus can do this, but I haven't tested it. (JoyToKey would work too as long as you don't need analog inputs.)